# SSRS Online CRM - get all Contacts born on a specific month

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

In SSRS using Fetch XML, as it is CRM Online, is there any way to get all Contacts born on a specific month? The month will be supplied in a parameter like the following:

Month : Jan,Feb,Mar,...,Dec

I know a few workarounds which can achieve this requirement without using FetchXML, but is there any way you can do this in CRM using solely FetchXML?

Comment: Before writing this question you surely have invested time into narrowing down your problem through trial and error; please, friend, share the fruits of this work with us so we do not need to repeat the process and can arrive at a beneficial solution sooner.

Comment: I think you are getting downvoted because your question isn't worded very well. It is actually a valid question, but unfortunately, also not possible (to my knowledge anyway). Tip: Keep your titles short and your question detailed but to the point. I am going to suggest an edit that removes a few vague statements, so don't hate me for it!

Comment: What version of CRM ? see if this helps https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#groupby_month

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you can't. There are several things you can do in an attempt to slice that data by months, but the best way (in my humble opinion) is just create a "Born On Month" field and populate it with a plugin. Then build your report off that instead.